# Transmitting multiple values to an Arduino, and interpreting them with minimum delay

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, ethernet-shield, joystick

I am building an underwater robot, which can move up/down and forward/reverse, controlled by a Joystick.

The situation is like this :

A USB joystick is connected to a PC, the PC is connected to an Arduino via a tether cable (Ethernet), and the motors of the robot are connected to the Arduino.

The joystick I am using has two sticks, and I have decided to use one stick to control the up/down movement (actually, I'm using only one axis of that stick for this) and the second stick to control the left/right movement.

Whenever the user manipulates both sticks simultaneously (to achieve diagonal motion, for example), the joystick will send two signals, one after the other, one for each stick.

Keeping in mind the limited receiver buffer size of the Arduino, how do I program the Arduino so that it can understand the difference between the linear motion signal and the diagonal motion signal?

I am highly motivated to program this on my own. I just need an intuition for this.

A thought came to my mind is, to use the following strategy:

For my up/down stick value, I add a character such as `U`, followed by the integer joystick value, e.g. I send `U4` to go up at speed `4`. With some twitching, I can even send a down signal with the same preceding character `U`.

Similarly, for forward/backward, I send `F` to go forward/backward at speed `3`. And for diagonal, I send something like `T5` to go diagonally at speed `5`.

My concern with this is that I will transmit two characters from the PC to the Arduino. Will the Arduino be able to read these two characters, interpret them and act accordingly, without a noticeable lag? Or is there an other better way?

This also makes me wonder, how commercial robots (such as commercial drones) handle such situations?

The movements the robot will make need to be quick. There should not be "visible" lag, that is, the user should not feel that the robot is responding after a couple of seconds.

Comment: How exactly are you transmitting data between PC and Arduino? As I understood, you use ethernet. But how are you sending and receiving the data itself? Simple packets? Web sockets? That can account for the biggest lag in the system

Comment: Take a look at CAN, most CAN controllers will have a buffer(s) to hold incoming packets. Each packet can have 8 bytes and you can run at a million bits a second. There are some that will go even faster but that would be good for the Arduino modules like the MPC2515 and they are not expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about commercial drones, however your 'protocol' seems to be quite efficient, as it uses 4 bytes to send 2 values (e.g. U3F5) for Up with speed 3 and Forward with speed 5.

Let's assume values from 0-7. Then you can send them both in 8 bits/one byte:

H H H H V V V V

Where H is the horizontal speed (from -8 (000) to +7 (111), in total 16 possible values.
For the vertical speed you can do the same.

So within one byte you send both speeds (meaning also there is no lag).
In case you need more accuracy, than send two bytes: one byte with horizontal and one byte with vertical speed. Depending on the sending/receiving speed I doubt there is any lag.

Even with your protocol I doubt there is a lag, but the above is more efficient.

I'm sure even more efficient algorithms can be created, probably by using the difference with the previous value (like sending delta values).

Another algorithm that can be created, assuming there is a big chance that only one of the two directions is changed (either horizontal or vertical is) and having a high accuracy

```
D V V V V V V V
```

Where D is the direction (0 = horizontal, 1 = vertical) and V is the value/speed (-64 to +63, 7 remaining bits).

Comment: The delta values might be problematic if a byte went missing, but otherwise a very nice idea!

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks ... It is also possible reserve another bit for a 'change' vs ''next value is absolute' value ... but that decreases the number of bits for the delta.